# concurrent programming in java using AbstractMonitor, how can i make a thread leave the monitor if a condition is met

Tags: java, multithreading

i'm trying to solve the sleeping barber problem in java i'm having a problem when trying to make a thread leave the monitor when a signle condition is met here's the code:

```
public void getHairCut(String threadName) {
    enter();
    if(!barberSleeping) {
        if(freeSeats == 0) {
        System.out.println(threadName + " waiting...");
            freeSeats--;;           
            hairCut.await();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("waiting room is full " + threadName + " is leaving...");
            return;   // i'm having a problem here,i want the thread to return     from the method and release the monitor's lock to let other threads enter
        }
    }
    // some code

    leave();
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not using standard Java synch mechanisms (e.g., `synchronized`, `wait`, `notify`) nor does your code show any sign of using advanced Java synch API (like `AtomicInt`, `Semaphone` etc.).

So could you please add more detail about the synchronization mechanisms you are using? Maybe show the implementation of `enter()` and `leave()`?

Comment: hi, this method is a method of a class i named Barbershop a monitor that extends the AbstractMonitor class so the enter() and leave() are methods of that class, i want to know how to make the thread leave the monitor at point where it finds that there are no seats availabe for it to wait.

Comment: I still cannot see which package `AbstractMonitor` comes from. Can you tell us? Anyway, I have given a more general answer. Maybe this helps already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you wrap the critical section in a try-finally block?

```
public void getHairCut(String threadName) {
    enter();
    try {
        if(!barberSleeping) {
            if(freeSeats == 0) {
            System.out.println(threadName + " waiting...");
                freeSeats--;;           
                hairCut.await();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("waiting room is full " + threadName + " is leaving...");
                return;   // i'm having a problem here,i want the thread to return     from the method and release the monitor's lock to let other threads enter
            }
        }
        // some code
    }
    finally {
        leave(); // this would be called in any case
    }
}
```

The `finally` block will be executed in any case:

- when execution reaches the bottom
- when an exception is thrown
- when the code block is quit because of a return statement

Comment: it worked!!, i didn't know about the try finally technique, that's exactly what i wanted,i learned something new today thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

In very brief the situation is as follows:

In order to be capable of waiting for a condition to be met a thread (say T0) must first acquire a lock for itself. After that it might (or might not) be suspended because some condition is not yet met by calling a wait-function. If this condition will be met at a later point (by another thread e.g. T1, because T0 is suspended), T1 might signal the suspended Thread T0 to reclaim its work. In order to signal the condition which was responsible for suspending T0, T1 also needs to acquire the one lock associated with the condition.

A corresponding code would look like:

```
// relevant prior assumptions

Lock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition myCondition = myLock.newCondition();

// code that might suspend thread T0
try {

    myLock.lock();

    while (someCondition == false) {

        myCondition.await();

    }

} finally {

    myLock.unlock();

}

// code that signals T0 to wake up and continue with its wrkr where it stopped (which is exactly aone line after the call to myCondition.awayit())

try {

    myLock.lock();

    myCondition.signal();
} finally {

    myLock.unlock();
}
```